# tycho-maven-plugin 3.0.0 Failed to collect dependencies

Tags: tycho

I'm trying to migrate to tycho 3.0.0 and get

`Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:3.0.0 -> org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.12.0 -> org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:jar:3.10.0 -> org.osgi.service:org.osgi.service.prefs:jar:[1.1.0,1.2.0)`

Obviously this is related to [maven-build-failed-due-to-jdt-dependencies-no-versions-available-for-org-osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625637/maven-build-failed-due-to-jdt-dependencies-no-versions-available-for-org-osgi)

Any attempt to force `org.eclipse.equinox.preferences` to resolve to something above 3.10.0 failed.

The following worked for `org.eclipse.core.runtime` (forced version 3.26.0) but not for `org.eclipse.equinox.preferences`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>         
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.preferences</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.100</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `org.osgi.service.prefs` is only in Eclipse 4.24 (2022-06) onwards. You seem to be mixing versions from different releases - that is likely to cause lots of problems. What is your target platform?

Comment: The target Platform is 2022-09. As far as I understand the error occurs when Maven tries to resolve the tycho components from maven central, before any target components play a role.
Maven seems not to resolve dependency ranges like [3.12.0,4.0.0) with the newest available version.

Comment: You are probably better off asking this on the [tycho discussions page](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions) but they will want more information about exactly what you are trying to do. Why do you need to specify any versions of plug-ins, that should all be automatic for a given target platform.

Comment: Even an example from https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho runs into the same problem, when switching to tycho 3.0.0. I will try again in a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an issue of the repository manager (archiva 2.2.4), which seems to provide the wrong versions. So I was completely on the wrong track.